# getting video duration with ffmpeg, php function

Tags: java, php, ffmpeg

I have FFMpeg installed and I know it's functional, but i'm trying to get the duration time from a flv video through PHP but when I use this code:

function mbmGetFLVDuration($file){

```
/*  
* Determine video duration with ffmpeg   
* ffmpeg should be installed on your server.  
*/  

//$time = 00:00:00.000 format   
$ffmpeg = "../ffmpeg/ffmpeg";

$time =  exec("$ffmpeg -i $file 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");   

$duration = explode(":",$time);   
$duration_in_seconds = $duration[0]*3600 + $duration[1]*60+ round($duration[2]);   

return $duration_in_seconds;
```

}

and:

$duration = mbmGetFLVDuration('http://www.videoaddsite.com/videos/intro.flv');
echo $duration;

I get an output of 220. THe video is 3:40. Can any help me on what i'm doing wrong, or if there's something else I can use?

Comment: You are getting output in seconds.. 220 seconds= 3:40 minutes

Answer (score 3):

I dont see a problem. 220 seconds are 3:40.

To get minutes and seconds use this conversion:

```
<?php
$seconds = 220;
$minutes = $seconds/60;
$real_minutes = floor($minutes);
$real_seconds = round(($minutes-$real_minutes)*60);
?>
```

`$real_minutes` will be 3 and `$real_seconds` will be 40.

Comment: Ha I feel dumb now. I've been working so much I tend to look over the small things. Haven't tried it yet but thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ffmpeg = "../ffmpeg/ffmpeg";

$time = exec("$ffmpeg -i $file 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");   

$duration = explode(":", $time);   
$duration_in_seconds = ($duration[0] * 3600) + ($duration[1] * 60) + round($duration[2]);   

return $duration_in_seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me

```
$file='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';

$dur = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$file." 2>&1");
if(preg_match("/: Invalid /", $dur)){
  return false;
}
preg_match("/Duration: (.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2})/", $dur, $duration);
if(!isset($duration[1])){
  return false;
}
$hours = $duration[1];
$minutes = $duration[2];
$seconds = $duration[3];

echo $seconds + ($minutes*60) + ($hours*60*60);
```

[Reference](https://mikedombrowski.com/2017/04/php-get-duration-of-a-media-file-using-ffmpeg/)